# jquery onclick event doesn't work, nothing happens

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to change the behavior of a button with jquery but i's not working, when I click the button of the modal nothing happens, the code insed the script tag it's not the definitive code, but helps to see if something happens.

```
...
</head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $( "#crear" ).click(function() {
              alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
            });
        </script>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Clases</a></li>
                <li><a href="office">Despachos</a></li>
                <li><a href="clase">Otros Servicios</a></li>
                <li><a href="clase">Administracion de usuario</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                  <h1>Editor de Clases</h1>
              </div>
               <div class = "row">
                  <p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                         Nuevo
                    </button>
                  <p>
             </div>

             <div class="row">
                 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Información</th>
                        <th>Opciones</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($clases as $clase_item){ 
                        //echo $clase_item->nombre;
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$clase_item->nombre."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$clase_item->info."</td>";
                            echo "<td align='center'>";
                            echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="clase/update/'.$clase_item->nombre.' ">Editar</a>';
                            echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="clase/delete/'.$clase_item->nombre.'">Borrar</a>';
                            echo "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";   
                    } ?>
             </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>

            <!--Modal para crear nueva clase-->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Crear nueva clase</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                    <?php $attributes = array('id' => 'modalform');?>
                    <?php echo form_open('clase/create',$attributes);?>  
                    <form class="form col-md-12 center-block">
                          <div id="error_msg"></div>    
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"  id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre"/>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="info" name="info" placeholder="Información"/>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <button id="crear"type="button"class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Crear</button>
                          </div>
                        </form>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!--Fin modal crear-->


    </body>
</html>
```

The code inside the script tag it's not been executed.

Comment: `document.ready`, `document.ready`, `document.ready`, `document.ready`, `document.ready`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [boombox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4240995/boombox) said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29835125/2319844), you need to run the script after the DOM is loaded. The best way to do this is to put your code inside a `document.ready`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $( "#crear" ).click(function() {
            alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hehe, yes. :) your answer is the common way for inline JS.

Comment: I added this code insede the head tag but it doen's work ,but it wotks at the bottom of the body

Comment: I have undeleted my answer and updated it. I showed a few ways to do this, including a faster way than using `ready()`.

Answer (score 2):

To be sure to handle this in the better possible way, put the following function before the closing body tag:

```
$(function () {
    $( "#crear" ).click(function() {
        alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
    });
});
```

This will be invoked as soon as the DOM is ready. This way is quicker to write!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because your `<script>` is running before the DOM for the body is loaded, so `$( "#crear" )` will be `null`.

Here are a few ways you can try:

1. You can create an event listener to listen for `DOMContentLoaded` without jQuery, like so:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { 
       // do stuff
   });
   ```
2. Or you can use jQuery:

   ```
   $(function () {
       // do stuff
   });
   ```

   The above is a quicker way of doing `$(document).ready()`.
3. Another way is to just move the `<script></script>` to the bottom before `</body>`.
4. For a modern flare, move your JS into an external file, add the `defer` attribute to your `<script>` like `<script defer>`, and then move it into the `<head>`. It should look something like:

   ```
   <script src="stuff.js" defer></script>
   ```

   within your `<head></head>`.

   ***Note:*** This method is supported in most, but not all, modern browsers. See [this page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer) for more information on which browsers are supported.

Comment: What browser versions are required to use `defer`?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your script in a fiddle and it worked.
https://jsfiddle.net/6g44zy04/

```
    $("#crear").click(function() {
      alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
    });
```

Are you correctly linking to jQuery? have you defined the var for jQuery to be something other than $?

Worth ensuring that this is load after the DOM has completed too.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// your code here
});
```